# is it possible to add new events in a ember view

Tags: jquery, ember.js, hammer.js

I have a small application, where the user can place divs on a stage.

These divs have to be draggable (and resizable) (via jQuery UI), further a choice of events should be fired, when the user interacts with a div (via hammer.js).

Current implementation:

```
App.DdView = Ember.View.extend({
    // ...
    didInsertElement: function (arg) {
        // some logic
        var $this = this.$();
        $this
            .draggable(/*...*/)
            .resizable(/*...*/);

        //delegate
        $(document).hammer().on("tap hold swipe", $this, function (e) {
            console.log(e.type)
        });
    }
    // ...
});
```

There are two problems:

1. if I bind the events to the $this element, the divs aren't draggable anymore (probably the mousedown event is default prevented). If I delegate the event (as shown in the code), the divs are draggable, but the events will fire on the whole document.
2. if there are placed more divs, the events are fired multiple.

So I thought, the smartest solution is to teach ember, that there are more events to handle than

```
'click', 'doubleClick', 'contextMenu' ...
```

I'd like to implement the event(handlers) as shown below:

```
App.DdView = Ember.View.extend({
    tap: function(){},
    hold: function(){},
    pinch: function(){},
    // ...
});
```

If there are much easier methods to realize this, feel free to post them.
thanks

---

Update:

changing the selector from   "$this"  to  "'#'+$this[0].id"  solves the problems, but it seems to be a very dirty solution.

```
$(document).hammer().on("tap hold swipe", '#'+$this[0].id, function (e) { ... });
```

So there's still the question if it's possible to teach ember the new events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really what I wanted, because I have to do this "workaround" in each view. But for now, this solution works fine:

```
var hammerEvents = ["touch", "release", "gesture", /* ... */];


didInsertElement: function (arg) {
    /* ... */
    var emthis = this,
        $this = this.$(),
        touchEvents = hammerEvents.join(" ");
    $(document).hammer().on(touchEvents, '#' + $this[0].id , function (e) {
        if (typeof emthis.get(e.type) == "function") {
            emthis.get(e.type).call(emthis);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@lukkysam, check out my project, ember-hammer, for integrating Hammer.js with Ember.js: https://github.com/chriswessels/ember-hammer

Sample usage:

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  hammerOptions: {
    swipe_velocity: 0.5
  },
  gestures: {
    swipeLeft: function (event) {
      // do something like send an event down the controller/route chain
      return false; // return `false` to stop bubbling
    }
  }
});
```